# Switching IMG based on Toggle Switch, is there something I'm missing?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code I'm working with, I'm attempting to get the images to switch when the box is checked and unchecked. It works with everything else like colors and width, etc.

```
<div class="theme-switch-wrapper col-md-3">
    <label class="theme-switch switch pull-right" for="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>

<script>
    const image = document.querySelector('.swoopImage');
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopDark.png';
        }
        else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            image.src = 'assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png';
        }
    }

    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
    </script>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="swoop">
    <img style="pointer-events: none;" class="swoopImage" src="assets/landingContentSwoopWhite.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

EDIT:

So I think the problem is that the `<script>` is nested in a bunch of divs, and the img div is outside that nest. But when I move the script to be global it breaks and nothing works.

Comment: When created as a `snippet` here it appears to work OK ( the image src changes but obviously the images do not load ) so it is not clear what the issue is. It might be preferable to locate all the JavaScript code towards the end of the page or ensure all the content is fully loaded ( use DOMContentLoaded event )before trying to invoke your code